# Make DIV same height as adjacent IMAGE using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, onload

Works on some browsers but not on Chrome!
Had to include a min-height which is ugly!
Even when onload fails, on Chrome, a window resize does work !
Its as if the onload is happening too soon.

Using js:

```
function resizeItemDiv()
{
var imgHeight=jQuery('.iw_itemImageBlock').first().height();
var paddingTop = parseInt(jQuery('.iw_itemIntroText').first().css("padding-top"));
var paddingBottom = parseInt(jQuery('.iw_itemIntroText').first().css("padding-   bottom"));
var marginBottom = parseInt(jQuery('.iw_itemIntroText').first().css("margin-bottom"));
var newHeight = imgHeight - paddingTop - paddingBottom - marginBottom;
jQuery('.iw_itemIntroText').css("height", newHeight);
return false;
}
jQuery(window).load(resizeItemDiv);
jQuery(window).resize(resizeItemDiv);
```

See page:

http://i-labeling.com/seminarhaus/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=filterfork2&mid=205&Itemid=309&f%5Bg%5D%5Btext%5D=&f%5Bg%5D%5Brange%5D%5B47%5D=

But it works OK on

[http://i-labeling.com/seminarhaus/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=98:cornelia-lachnitt&Itemid=309](http://i-labeling.com/seminarhaus/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=98%3acornelia-lachnitt&Itemid=309)

Comment: you should really think about caching `jQuery('.iw_itemIntroText').first()` in a var as you use it multiple times but you also foget to minus top and bottom border.  Also looks fine in chrome to me

Comment: Thanks Pete - caching?? never used but will look into it. Also I think I only gave the GOOD example when you looked! Please try the first link in Chrome.